# Get current indentation inside an escape within lstlisting

Tags: listings

I'm typesetting source code with the `listings` package's `lstlisting` environment. Since I have to draw custom stuff in some lines, I use `escapeinside` in these lines to insert a `tikzpicture`.

Since these lines may be indented, I need to know the length of the indentation, or the remaining width of the line. Is there any way to access that?
`\linewidth` still contains the full line length, so a box of width `\linewidth` sticks out on the right as much as the line was indented.

---

For example, consider this document:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{listings}

\begin{document}

\newcommand{\mwebox}{\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline]\path[fill=black!10, draw=black!0, thick] (0,-0.20) rectangle (5, 0.30);\end{tikzpicture}}

\begin{lstlisting}[escapeinside=~~]
Test
~\mwebox~
Test

    Test
    ~\mwebox~
    Test
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

I want to extend the gray boxes to the end of the lines.

Comment: Please give a full [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228). Currently we have to guess what packages etc you are using and this makes it really hard to help you. A MWE should start with a `\documentclass` command, have a minimal preamble  and then `\begin{document}...\end{document}`. The code should compile and be as small as possible to demonstrate your problem. This makes it much easier for people to help you --- and much more likely that they will!

Comment: I added a minimal document that could use this length.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't really answering your question as I am not doing this automatically, but I think that you probably need to manually tweak your `tikzpicture` environment because the [listings](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/listings) manual says "indention must be done by hand".

For example, using

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{listings}

\begin{document}

\newcommand{\mwebox}[1][12]{\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline]\path[fill=black!10, draw=black!0, thick] (0,-0.20) rectangle (#1, 0.30);\end{tikzpicture}}

\begin{lstlisting}[escapeinside=~~]
Test
~\mwebox~
Test

    Test
    ~\mwebox[11.2]~
    Test
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

gives the output that I think you want:

[image]

So, I have defined `\mwebox` to have an optional argument that defaults to 12, which is close to the margin. I then found `11.2` by trial and error for the second box.

Comment: That's what I've been doing so far, but getting these numbers right is awful, and of course it always feels like your're *just a bit* off...